# iPhone App crashing on launch on iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c

iPhone application is crashing on launch in the iOS 4.1 but working in later versions and iOS 4.0. This is the crash log got from the device, I am not able to point out the issue

```
Incident Identifier: F3B50401-19DE-4E41-BFB4-C0D904D73C06
CrashReporter Key:   7df1d68c8b14e4afa43c08cf96c7221621953e69
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         POCNew [1592]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2E4FF8FF-2AB1-4F1F-86B8-231029FB4E1D/POCNew.app/POCNew
Identifier:      POCNew
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-13 14:57:31.569 +0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00078ac8 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00078ab8 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00078aaa raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d03a abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00005958 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004838 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000a16f8 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000491d2 ___forwarding___ + 502
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00048f88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  POCNew                          0x00002a66 0x1000 + 6758
14  UIKit                           0x0000e47a -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 766
15  UIKit                           0x000049e0 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 200
16  UIKit                           0x0005dfd6 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1390
17  UIKit                           0x0005d8fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
18  UIKit                           0x0005d330 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5104
19  GraphicsServices                0x00005044 PurpleEventCallback + 660
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00034cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00034ca0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00027566 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
25  UIKit                           0x000040fc -[UIApplication _run] + 364
26  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
27  POCNew                          0x0000249c 0x1000 + 5276
28  POCNew                          0x0000241c 0x1000 + 5148

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6b6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d65bc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d675c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a67a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x000024e2 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e0862b4
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x0024b3bc      r6: 0x2fffe1c8      r7: 0x2fffe1d8
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x3ea50618     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffe1d8      lr: 0x30277abf      pc: 0x30277ac8
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xb6fff +POCNew armv7  <a9184ded427e3ced882486662d4e1aea> /var/mobile/Applications/2E4FF8FF-2AB1-4F1F-86B8-231029FB4E1D/POCNew.app/POCNew
  0x66c000 -   0x66dfff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
  0x671000 -   0x675fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <fdb3b200d0f23446df9f23d931ee1e39> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <a11905c8ef7906bf4b8910fc551f9dbb> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3002b000 - 0x300ebfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <49029949741e10f21b178b0a4b2df979> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x300ff000 - 0x30141fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <75ae0cfae42b263eb4de427a1b991f9a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x30187000 - 0x3018afff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <eb847a9560239a5cdd1f19fc6195ecb8> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x301ff000 - 0x3030cfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0792bef82e8cde31cb32d06e80262288> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x303b3000 - 0x303bcfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <527d15dc1e27c410c7474f306769a0a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x30791000 - 0x3079bfff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <8c3b9937841c974fde7b3e26d2ff5f7d> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
0x307a0000 - 0x307a1fff  CoreSurface armv7  <586f25579330ac060decd2df4cc05bd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x307ef000 - 0x307f7fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <e86dd3313cbef5a3a0fb8598f6b0ab18> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x307f8000 - 0x308cbfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <adb562d8b5eaadbb874e255a09d0e04b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x308cc000 - 0x30979fff  MapKit armv7  <f81ff5a3f136586c154de56851378806> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x30996000 - 0x30a7efff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <ef656cb58e56a36789ee17d4d925e9ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30a7f000 - 0x30a87fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <6fb15d72d3ee5444d901dc9ef974a3b3> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30a88000 - 0x30ac2fff  IOKit armv7  <6810c1b44dd12227780dc88c76b692e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30ac9000 - 0x30ad0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0011bd5af0230fcaf63005f7eefa11dd> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30ad5000 - 0x30ad7fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8b23f794f02c2f7572a8fe6532630161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x30ae8000 - 0x30b13fff  DataAccess armv7  <7320fc47e54348166062dcfcc4c17439> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x30b44000 - 0x30b8ffff  GMM armv7  <140d9a6633393f644c3aa852fe7e7e42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x30bb3000 - 0x30bbffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <b715ca60b9e99b3b2b4f8270c478c138> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30bc8000 - 0x30c59fff  ImageIO armv7  <3f421780e67f0219e416287d3e684b54> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x30c5a000 - 0x30cfafff  Celestial armv7  <aa0773c3d8e022e5a0b307b1db79232a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30cfb000 - 0x30d2afff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <b79a5a4f0506ce17bedeef7799e81687> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30d49000 - 0x30e6ffff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed7b56f98da764e4639611ae6327417b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30f4b000 - 0x30f82fff  Security armv7  <4770002d4b443c186dc1e3ddaa1787c8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30f8b000 - 0x30fbbfff  AppSupport armv7  <20908678e860c23207574337097b94f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30fc3000 - 0x31201fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <ef4a9b7fdccb3317b5b620ae59a70490> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3120e000 - 0x3121cfff  Notes armv7  <22108af89c58bf3bf01c7109915dad9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31224000 - 0x31292fff  AVFoundation armv7  <05feb4f546c261049ccc8d6a5ccf8790> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31295000 - 0x31382fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <485fd1df5d59421108c9f006a1aca6c6> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x313a6000 - 0x313a8fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <ef3a36680985b4db12a778d62f37961f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x313af000 - 0x31448fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <3f29fbbfe5abb8969cda45e0efe42af5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31499000 - 0x314a4fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31509000 - 0x31537fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <41663f59614034ba151e9b4f86e1e141> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31565000 - 0x31572fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6bdd1b930c09cfec7c6c7629551c0cbd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31574000 - 0x3157dfff  AccountSettings armv7  <aba19b26f9a5e950bd9861c93e265a3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x315ec000 - 0x31601fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31619000 - 0x3171dfff  CoreData armv7  <36b5f42fcdceea61bedb2838f8279714> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x318c3000 - 0x3196afff  WebKit armv7  <a8bfa45e5c19efcf95e184e658d61a18> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31adb000 - 0x31ae4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <d47b741a05fdbed287a454e834aeede2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31ae6000 - 0x31afcfff  EAP8021X armv7  <419b97910c4b517f38697a3121775bc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x31afd000 - 0x31b3ffff  MessageUI armv7  <f531fb1f0d3cc0922d643597f5ef23a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x31bb1000 - 0x31bdafff  ContentIndex armv7  <1b790132dfce754bee3775628f26c8eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x31bdf000 - 0x31be2fff  CertUI armv7  <4d350d880f67fad89bc143e7159c1ac0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31be3000 - 0x31c1dfff  CoreMedia armv7  <c85a11d97cb8820e325db898b0740f2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31c20000 - 0x31c20fff  vecLib armv7  <e1d93756e63104d2861a277e8a70df44> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31c25000 - 0x31c36fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <23a6206a542a6b02dd4c5103af3f9da2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x31c6c000 - 0x31c6efff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2b26c74e98505a26da656eeb781b16cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31c88000 - 0x31c8efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <e89050debe57ae71a3f0ed2bc9c46145> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31d2d000 - 0x31d34fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <e8c579a3faa687bfb52ba68fbe7b17be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31e40000 - 0x31e4cfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7075593b53fcd90c8d2aa40ba9ff4397> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x31e4d000 - 0x3308dfff  UIKit armv7  <3f1f8f7555dcf93cc4ce2146286bd3f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x330af000 - 0x33601fff  WebCore armv7  <4d60fdc638b6218c26d3c143af5e829c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x337dd000 - 0x337fcfff  Bom armv7  <f49558f211241498f37af577051611b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x337fd000 - 0x33830fff  iCalendar armv7  <4e036eca5114ea49caf2a80ca52e9d0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33847000 - 0x33876fff  CoreText armv7  <0855144a7f9eeade285f2e7c030f7478> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33877000 - 0x33908fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <99283bc397692fbf3c296b0c1a298aed> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x3390e000 - 0x33951fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <deafb4c98c723215e43f07c3bf6d77e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3396a000 - 0x3399dfff  AddressBook armv7  <59286907142fc76ead3dab9fa3baff5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3399e000 - 0x339b6fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <6d9b86e946a18416f1a50586beabd716> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x339bc000 - 0x339bffff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <6c367af97f27bcdac9362897e0bae546> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x339c7000 - 0x339cafff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0d33b320dcac6cb6a594171f3f8c3b04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x339dd000 - 0x339e5fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <a19586adf6b24dabd61f3f56a350a042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x339e6000 - 0x339e9fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <1f8c5b5641eba117423f385dda0dffa3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x339ea000 - 0x33a93fff  QuartzCore armv7  <1628da07ea69b89c0b6a5a7d2dc42a24> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33a94000 - 0x33aa6fff  VoiceServices armv7  <0516eeee20637169a6cff84ce7c37a93> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x33aa7000 - 0x33ad5fff  MIME armv7  <0cbbaadc15780476e4fcdcdf14bbe4ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x33b7a000 - 0x33b8afff  GeoServices armv6  <e8151d936c117b840b906ca32aa2e2e4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x33b8b000 - 0x33bd0fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <7de3ef8f02a0af58ef9f58348d5dbc50> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33bfc000 - 0x33d17fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <6dcc299d5ca75f73afbc98a1b4bd2c7a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33d21000 - 0x33d8ffff  ProofReader armv7  <184b846e1f602485068db7a9c943595f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33d91000 - 0x33d95fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0c10a998f46151b69a9060b5879973cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33eb5000 - 0x33ee4fff  QuickLook armv7  <0e54a89bb297491e416dbc51a542fdd6> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33ee5000 - 0x33ef4fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <17fc35fddaa84a39ca7f260b9f220e4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x33f5a000 - 0x33f99fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <f261ea6e5f00e4ba4fda02bb4d7712b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33fc2000 - 0x33fc5fff  ActorKit armv7  <bc4365d27ab1fcdf780d64c4d180e417> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33fc6000 - 0x33fc7fff  DataMigration armv7  <c2889c5e6185ac7ef67fe4147344d410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x33fde000 - 0x34087fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34091000 - 0x340dbfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <7b2a8cf02f12c636c6db7f5e1906f9f0> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x340fc000 - 0x34396fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <795a79616d24a733fae53d9df6c46998> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34464000 - 0x34503fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <28583b202a5108a6e93c9990a2f1d576> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x34504000 - 0x34537fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e4fb7d0e9675955039ed7a452c3dc935> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34538000 - 0x34568fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <fbd7776498c593443b467d5dc31d2615> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x34569000 - 0x345befff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ec6199ca9490baba91f9bc644063bef1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x345bf000 - 0x345cffff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <51e935a31a31072ec7a10b7b80adc85e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x346d8000 - 0x346e1fff  ITSync armv7  <6de2eeb0276458257e6c972f7195a787> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x346e7000 - 0x3473dfff  EventKit armv7  <f560f34fe9f784df16c7451a7c3d5a76> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3473e000 - 0x34740fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee5bb3b14b91bcf192f0d18e9f31c40a> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34781000 - 0x34786fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <dabd32c6bac583a6809c2b04c5907acf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34787000 - 0x348b7fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <9420239a007f28f7aa2163b05053d110> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x348ba000 - 0x348fafff  CoreAudio armv7  <96e6c0b793449c9e08a507693c956aad> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34906000 - 0x34951fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9e5eadf1538d47142a4257d2fa5bbdd5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34979000 - 0x3497cfff  IOSurface armv7  <83927fd3641791e5bcdadcca0edd196b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x349a7000 - 0x34ac6fff  Foundation armv7  <5cffb5458e87beccdb75770cea676753> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34ad1000 - 0x34ad7fff  IAP armv7  <e0bde1a923179f4eaea83b8e8ca602d7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34ad8000 - 0x34ae5fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <df1574298fea28ad799e1549425b44a4> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34af1000 - 0x34af4fff  ApplePushService armv7  <ee70c20a69f16dd4d43e4489903047bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x34b3c000 - 0x34c55fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <71ef015f1994cf85658df91a50a37815> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34c56000 - 0x34c56fff  Accelerate armv7  <0601858b149ba0586210ad15b0d41c1e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34cdf000 - 0x34da1fff  CFNetwork armv7  <0860d900e5328f349290feaaa3eb6e9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x34daa000 - 0x34dc9fff  MobileSync armv7  <3dfdf772f29393bcca4fa113b46cee52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x34fc8000 - 0x34fdbfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <e47fe2a55644ffd53fab6547ef59ffab> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34fed000 - 0x35074fff  Message armv7  <0811df7f3cfa8b9c241cd3bdf06de209> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x35122000 - 0x3514bfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <fe6ab911eb680b758f415e20afec8e00> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x35414000 - 0x35500fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <6e60d6565924f03d819e330080fc0dfe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
```

Comment: Do you use this  defined() or kCTVerticalFormsAttributeName  in your app?

Comment: no..i haven't used any of those

Answer (score 0):

My guess on the info supplied looks like it's just calling an unknown method in 4.1 from line...

```
13  POCNew                          0x00002a66 0x1000 + 6758
```

that is the app is calling on an API that is missing or changed in that OS version... perhaps it's not a public API you're calling or something that was flagged to be deprecated in 4.0?

If you have the symbol file you can find out exactly what line it is.  I believe this link talks through that process if it helps.

[Getting Info on debugging addresses](http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/2011/03/processing-users-crash-logs-when.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .dYSM file along with the crash log to more thoroughly analyse the issue.
you must have .dYSM file in the build folder where your .app is generated.
you should use the same version of .dYSM with your .app